# Help with searching for files in C#

Tags: c#, regex, search, replace

I am working on a search and replace console app to help out some people in my department.  I am trying to have them input a file path and also the type of file they would like to search for.  if they want to find txt files then it will find all txt files in a directory...stick these into an array and then process the files as needed.  I am able to do the search and replace part.

I am new to C# and have a solution working in Python, but they want it more portable.

Comment: To expand on this since it can be seen as a vague.  I have a top level directory and then several sub-directories...I need to walk through all of the sub-directories and find the files that match a certain file extension.  I am able to get this to work if the top level directory has the files in it, but it doesn't go below that.  is there a way to get it to include all sub-directories as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
string path = @"C:\temp";
string searchPattern = "*.txt";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
foreach (string f in files)
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always port it to [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) if they are worried about .Net compatibility.

Comment: It is more of an exercise to help me learn C#...since it is part of my job and all.  But I do appreciate the answer...

Answer (score 0):

This question is really too broad, we aren't going to write the code for you.

However, here are some links to functionality common in this type of app:

Listing Files in a Directory:

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=356

Reading and Writing Files:

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

Hope that is a good enough head start.

Comment: For some reason I was hitting a wall...just needed a push and wasn't expecting anyone to write my code, I appreciate the answer not the insinuation.